# How can I create a Liquibase XML changelog file from a restored database?

Tags: liquibase

how to create liquibase XML from restored DB

create liquibase XML from restored DB and adding it to terraform module so that the process could be automated partially . And also need some references if possible to create a test or poc of the same !